# Haskell: apply a polymorphic function twice

Tags: haskell

We can have a polymorphic function `f :: a -> b` implemented for different pairs of `a` and `b`. How can we make

```
twice :: (a -> b) -> a -> c
twice f x = f (f x)
```

type check? i.e. how can I write a function which applies a *polymorphic* function twice?

With [`Rank2Types`](https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/Rank2Types) we can get a bit closer but not quite there:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}

twice1 :: (forall a. a -> (m a)) -> b -> (m (m b))
twice1 f = f . f

twice2 :: (forall a. m a -> a) -> m (m b) -> b
twice2 f = f . f
```

so then some polymorphic functions can be applied twice:

```
\> twice1 (:[]) 1
[[1]]
\> twice2 head [[1]]
1
```

Can we go further?

[The question was asked over Haskell cafe](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2006-November/thread.html#19456) *10 years ago* but wasn't quite answered (with type classes it becomes a lot of boilerplate).

Comment: Is `twice :: Functor f => (forall a . f a -> g a) -> (forall a . f (f a) -> g (g a))` good enough? `twice=twice1` with `f~Identity`, and `twice=twice2` with `g~Identity`. Something like `twice (Id . head) . twice (\(Id a) -> [a])` for example, works.

Answer (score 4):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, RankNTypes, UnicodeSyntax #-}

type family Fundep a :: *

type instance Fundep Bool = Int
type instance Fundep Int = String
...

twice :: ∀ a . (∀ c . c -> Fundep c) -> a -> Fundep (Fundep a)
twice f = f . f
```

Now, that won't be much use actually because you can't define a (meaningful) polymorphic function that works with *any* `c`. One possibility is to toss in a class constraint, like

```
class Showy a where
  type Fundep a :: *
  showish :: a -> Fundep a

instance Showy Bool where
  type Fundep Bool = Int
  showish = fromEnum
instance Showy Int where
  type Fundep Int = String
  showish = show

twice :: ∀ a b . (Showy a, b ~ Fundep a, Showy b) =>
    (∀ c . Showy c => c -> Fundep c) -> a -> Fundep b
twice f = f . f

main = print $ twice showish False
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't make `twice` generic enough even in a dependently typed setting, but it's possible with intersection types:

```
twice :: (a -> b /\ b -> c) -> a -> c
twice f x = f (f x)
```

Now whenever `f :: a -> b` and `f :: b -> c` typecheck, `twice` will typecheck too.

There is also a beautiful spell in [Benjamin Pierce's thesis](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/pierce.pdf) (I changed the syntax slightly):

```
self : (A /\ A -> B) -> B
self f = f f
```

So self-application is typeable with intersection types as well.