# How to write "twice" so it can accept "swap" without restricting their type

Tags: haskell, type-theory

If I have these definitions

```
twice f = f . f

swap (x,y) = (y,x)
```

The type of twice is infered to `(a -> a) -> a -> a` and swap is infered to `(a,b) -> (b,a)`.

If I write `swap . swap` the type of that expression is `(a, b) -> (a, b)`.

But if I ask for `twice swap` its type is `(a, a) -> (a, a)`.

I know that `twice` is restricting the type of `swap`. But I'm wondering if there is a way to write `twice` so that it accepts `swap` without restricting its type. That is, you can write `twice swap` and accept pairs where each component has a different type.

The same happens with `flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c`, because `twice flip :: (a -> a -> b) -> a -> a -> b`.

Comment: The difference, I think, is that in `swap . swap`, `(.)` is getting two "indepedent" polymorphic functions, so type unification can treat them separately. `twice swap`, however, has to pass the *same* function as both arguments to `(.)`, so the type must be fixed before `(.)` sees it.

Comment: The `ImpredicativeTypes` extension might be applicable, though? (I haven't gotten it to work, but that's not saying much since I don't fully understand it.)

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate: [Haskell: How to create most generic function possible that applies a function to tuple items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31220903/7509065)

Comment: related question [Haskell: apply a polymorphic function twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35542271/haskell-apply-a-polymorphic-function-twice), and an article I wrote [What is the type of `\f x -> f (f x)`?](https://github.com/rampion/DoubleApplication)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is tricky to do, because you need to express that the result- and argument types are polymorphic, yet in a particular functional relationship. You need to provide this relationship in an explicit way. The most common way of expressing a type-level function is with a type family, but such functions can not be named as first-class entities. Also they can't encode the bidirectional natural of type relations like in `swap`.

What you can do instead is represent the function with a unique type-tag, and link the argument- and result types together with a MPTC.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies, AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

class PolyFun f a b | f a -> b, f b -> a where
  once :: a -> b

data Swap

instance PolyFun Swap (a,b) (b,a) where
  once = swap
```

Now,

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications, UnicodeSyntax #-}

twice :: ∀ f a b c . (PolyFun f a b, PolyFun f b c) => a -> c
twice = once @f @b @c . once @f @a @b
```

```
GHCi> twice @Swap (3, "hi")
(3,"hi")
```

This is *fairly* versatile,

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances      #-}

data Concat

instance PolyFun Concat [[a]] [a] where
  once = concat

data Flip

instance PolyFun Flip (a -> b -> c) (b -> a -> c) where
  once = flip
```

```
GHCi> twice @Concat [ [[1,2,3],[4,5]], [[6,7],[8]] ]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
GHCi> twice @Flip (/) 9 3
3.0
```

but it has its limitations as well, in particular the way I wrote it above the argument and result of the function must be inferrable from each other. But for many functions, only the argument type can be inferred from the result type and not vice versa, or sometimes only the result type from the arguments. You would have to use different classes to cover all the possible ways the type information can flow, I don't think there's a single way that does it all automatically.

---

**Edit** It turns out there *is* actually a single way that does it automatically, but, erm... *don't try this at home, kids*...

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies, AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications, UnicodeSyntax #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, DataKinds, PolyKinds, GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, ConstraintKinds, FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, TypeOperators, UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Kind (Type, Constraint)

import Data.Tuple (swap)

import Data.These


class HasThis (t :: These k k) where
  type UseThis t :: k

instance HasThis ('This a) where
  type UseThis ('This a) = a
instance HasThis ('These a b) where
  type UseThis ('These a b) = a

class HasThat (t :: These k k) where
  type UseThat t :: k

instance HasThat ('That b) where
  type UseThat ('That b) = b
instance HasThat ('These a b) where
  type UseThat ('These a b) = b

data TheseSing (t :: These k k) where
  ThisS :: TheseSing ('This a)
  ThatS :: TheseSing ('That b)
  TheseS :: TheseSing ('These a b)

class TFun f where
  type Accepted f a :: Constraint
  type ($) f a :: Type

type TfnT = Type

class PolyFun f where
  type Inferences f :: These TfnT TfnT
  inferences :: TheseSing (Inferences f)
  once_fti :: ( HasThis (Inferences f)
              , TFun (UseThis (Inferences f))
              , Accepted (UseThis (Inferences f)) a
              )
                  => a -> (UseThis (Inferences f) $ a)
  once_rti :: ( HasThat (Inferences f)
              , TFun (UseThat (Inferences f))
              , Accepted (UseThat (Inferences f)) b
              )
                  => (UseThat (Inferences f) $ b) -> b

class ForwardInf i x y | i x -> y where
  usingThisFwd :: ∀ r .
       ( ( TFun i, Accepted i x
         , y ~ (i $ x) )
         => r ) -> r
instance ( TFun i, Accepted i x
         , y ~ (i $ x) )
      => ForwardInf i x y where
  usingThisFwd φ = φ

class ReverseInf i x y | i y -> x where
  usingThatRev :: ∀ r .
       ( ( TFun i, Accepted i y
         , x ~ (i $ y) )
         => r ) -> r
instance ( TFun i, Accepted i y
         , x ~ (i $ y) )
      => ReverseInf i x y where
  usingThatRev φ = φ

type family AnyTI infs :: Type -> Type -> Constraint where
  AnyTI ('This i) = ForwardInf i
  AnyTI ('That i) = ReverseInf i
  AnyTI ('These i e) = ForwardInf i

once :: ∀ f x y . (PolyFun f, AnyTI (Inferences f) x y) => x -> y
once = case inferences @f of
  ThisS -> usingThisFwd @(UseThis (Inferences f)) @x @y (once_fti @f @x)
  ThatS -> usingThatRev @(UseThat (Inferences f)) @x @y (once_rti @f @y)
  TheseS -> usingThisFwd @(UseThis (Inferences f)) @x @y (once_fti @f @x)

data Swap

type family SwapT t where
  SwapT (a,b) = (b,a)

class IsTuple t where
  type Fst t :: Type
  type Snd t :: Type
  deconstructTuple :: (t ~ (Fst t, Snd t) => r) -> r

instance IsTuple (a,b) where
  type Fst (a,b) = a
  type Snd (a,b) = b
  deconstructTuple φ = φ

instance TFun Swap where
  type ($) Swap t = SwapT t
  type Accepted Swap t = IsTuple t

fti_swap :: ∀ t . IsTuple t => t -> SwapT t
fti_swap = deconstructTuple @t swap

rti_swap :: ∀ t . IsTuple t => SwapT t -> t
rti_swap = deconstructTuple @t swap

instance PolyFun Swap where
  type Inferences Swap = 'These Swap Swap
  inferences = TheseS
  once_fti = fti_swap
  once_rti = rti_swap

data Compose f g

instance (TFun f, TFun g) => TFun (Compose f g) where
  type Accepted (Compose f g) a = (Accepted g a, Accepted f (g$a))
  type ($) (Compose f g) a = f $ (g$a)

class CompShared (a :: These Type Type) (b :: These Type Type) where
  type Shared a b :: These Type Type
  sharingFwd :: ∀ x r . ( HasThis (Shared a b)
                        , Accepted (UseThis (Shared a b)) x )
        => (( HasThis a, HasThis b
            , TFun (UseThis a), TFun (UseThis b)
            , Accepted (UseThis b) x
            , Accepted (UseThis a) (UseThis b $ x)
            , (UseThis (Shared a b) $ x) ~ (UseThis a $ (UseThis b $ x)) )
             => r) -> r
  sharingRev :: ∀ y r . ( HasThat (Shared a b)
                        , Accepted (UseThat (Shared a b)) y )
        => (( HasThat a, HasThat b
            , TFun (UseThat a), TFun (UseThat b)
            , Accepted (UseThat a) y
            , Accepted (UseThat b) (UseThat a $ y)
            , (UseThat (Shared a b) $ y) ~ (UseThat b $ (UseThat a $ y)) )
             => r) -> r
  shared :: TheseSing (Shared a b)

instance (TFun f, TFun g) => CompShared ('This f) ('This g) where
  type Shared ('This f) ('This g) = 'This (Compose f g)
  shared = ThisS
  sharingFwd φ = φ
  sharingRev _ = undefined

instance (TFun f, TFun g) => CompShared ('This f) ('These g c) where
  type Shared ('This f) ('These g c) = 'This (Compose f g)
  shared = ThisS
  sharingFwd φ = φ
  sharingRev _ = undefined

instance (TFun f, TFun g) => CompShared ('That f) ('That g) where
  type Shared ('That f) ('That g) = 'That (Compose g f)
  shared = ThatS
  sharingFwd _ = undefined
  sharingRev φ = φ

instance (TFun f, TFun g) => CompShared ('That f) ('These c g) where
  type Shared ('That f) ('These c g) = 'That (Compose g f)
  shared = ThatS
  sharingFwd _ = undefined
  sharingRev φ = φ

instance (TFun f, TFun g, TFun h, TFun i)
            => CompShared ('These f h) ('These g i) where
  type Shared ('These f h) ('These g i) = 'These (Compose f g) (Compose i h)
  shared = TheseS
  sharingFwd φ = φ
  sharingRev φ = φ

data Twice f

twice_fti :: ∀ f x .
       ( PolyFun f
       , CompShared (Inferences f) (Inferences f)
       , HasThis (Shared (Inferences f) (Inferences f))
       , Accepted (UseThis (Shared (Inferences f) (Inferences f))) x )
     => x -> (UseThis (Shared (Inferences f) (Inferences f)) $ x)
twice_fti = sharingFwd @(Inferences f) @(Inferences f) @x
               (once_fti @f . once_fti @f)

twice_rti :: ∀ f y .
       ( PolyFun f
       , CompShared (Inferences f) (Inferences f)
       , HasThat (Shared (Inferences f) (Inferences f))
       , Accepted (UseThat (Shared (Inferences f) (Inferences f))) y )
     => (UseThat (Shared (Inferences f) (Inferences f)) $ y) -> y
twice_rti = sharingRev @(Inferences f) @(Inferences f) @y
               (once_rti @f . once_rti @f)

instance (PolyFun f, CompShared (Inferences f) (Inferences f))
             => PolyFun (Twice f) where
  type Inferences (Twice f) = Shared (Inferences f) (Inferences f)
  inferences = shared @(Inferences f) @(Inferences f)
  once_fti = twice_fti @f
  once_rti = twice_rti @f

twice :: ∀ f x y . (PolyFun (Twice f), AnyTI (Inferences (Twice f)) x y) => x -> y
twice = once @(Twice f)

data FromInteger

instance TFun FromInteger where
  type Accepted FromInteger a = Integral a
  type ($) FromInteger a = Integer

instance PolyFun FromInteger where
  type Inferences FromInteger = That FromInteger
  inferences = ThatS
  once_fti = undefined
  once_rti = fromInteger
```

```
GHCi> twice @Swap (1, "hi")
(1,"hi")
GHCi> twice @FromInteger 5
5
```

Comment: What is `AllowAmbiguousTypes` for? And one more question, what does it mean that "It turns out there is actually a single way that does it automatically"? I see that you're still passing @Swap as an argument. Very good answer though!

Comment: The type of `once` is _ambiguous_ because `f` doesn't turn up anywhere in the signature `once :: a -> b`. I.e. it's not possible to infer the concrete instance from a context in which `once` is used, you always need to explicitly specify `f` with a `TypeApplication`, i.e. `once @Swap`.

Comment: Right, so as far as I understand there is no way to solve it without being explicit about the type of `swap`, right?

Answer (score 16):

Yes, but not usefully. Without changing `twice`'s implementation, you can change its type. If you change its type to require a function which acts specifically like `swap` (i.e., that it flips the order of type arguments to some type constructor, without caring about the details of those type arguments), then you can compose that function with itself.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

twice :: (forall a b. f a b -> f b a) -> f a b -> f a b
twice f = f . f

> :t twice swap
twice swap :: (a, b) -> (a, b)
```

You can't use this for `flip` directly, because currying associates the type parameters in the wrong order for us. But you can use a newtype to reorder things if you're explicit about the function being two-argument:

```
newtype BiFunction r a b = Bi {unBi :: a -> b -> r}
flipBi = Bi . flip . unBi

> :t twice flipBi
twice flipBi :: BiFunction r a b -> BiFunction r a b
```

The problem is that this makes `twice` pretty useless for any other task. You can no longer write `twice succ` to get a function that adds 2, for example, because `succ` doesn't have this property that it reorders type parameters. `twice f` is almost required to be the identity function, because it can't inspect or modify the values of type `a` or `b` at all. It can change the context in `f`, though, so you could define `someFunction`, `Pair`, and `Empty` such that `twice someFunction (Pair 1 2) = Empty`. Give it a try if you think it'd be an interesting exercise.

Comment: Yes, don't being to be able to do `twice succ` is pretty annoying since that's pretty basic example of application of the twice function. But at least your solution doesn't use a lot of language extensions.